# Как скрыть середину текста разной длины?

Tags: php

Имеем следующее (пример):

```
niwn8342t242r24nutv942ucnt
wfgvwetq4t4tc34tvq3
34tvq34ty5v4yct34tcc3
4ct4c43
4ctc44ct34tv34t4c34ct34ct3rc34tr324c
```

Результат (по 5 символов в начале и в конце, остальное скрыть точками):

```
niwn8...2ucnt
wfgvw...4tvq3
34tvq...4tcc3
4ct4c43
4ctc4...r324c
```

> Хотелось бы пример одной строкой

Comment: PS. Для примера каждая строка это значение массива в цикле `foreach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Хотелось бы пример одной строкой*

```
$str = '4ctc44ct34tv34t4c34ct34ct3rc34tr324c';

echo preg_replace('~(.{5}).+(.{5})~', '$1...$2', $str);
```

Результат:

```
4ctc4...r324c
```